# How to quit this comment in Git Bash

Tags: git, gitbucket

[image]

While I use Git Bash ,I encountered this phenomenon,but I can't return command terminal.
How to solve this problem and what is the reason such phenomenon is occurred?

Comment: Press `Esc` and then enter `:x`. This is vim which is a text editor used to edit the merge commit message.

Comment: yes,you are right.I tried to pull from master branch and then this phenomenon is occurred,message is appeared : merge in not finished ,but I can't know what is the unmerged and how to solve this problem.
I hope your help.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=git+commit+terminal+blocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

press `esc` then `:q!` to exit vim without save.

and next time try to `pull` or `merge` with option `--no-edit` to commit without changing its commit message.